# Changing an attribute on certain future elements when they appear in jQuery - it's possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I need a sort of "live" effect on some checkbox - I need that every checkbox since now will be checked by a jQuery function `attr("checked", true)` when they appear.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: how would that checkbox appear... it would depend on how they appear in the future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `success` handler, or the `success` handler of whatever short form of `$.ajax()` you're using, (e.g. [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), etc.), like this:

```
$.ajax({
  //options...
  success: function(data) {
    $("input:checkbox", data).attr("checked", true);
  }
});
```

This is the most optimal way to accomplish what you're after, by giving it a [context](http://api.jquery.com/context/) to look in...so it's only looking for `input:checkbox` in the returned result you're now adding to the DOM, not the entire page.

If that's not possible, you can use something like the [livequery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery), like this:

```
$("input:checkbox").livequery(function() {
  $(this).attr("checked", true);
});
```

This is more expensive due to the way it looks for new elements to be added, but gets the job done.